# Question about expressions in Field Theory

Tags: polynomials

How I can express $(\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha^2 - \alpha)$  and $(1-\alpha)^{-1}$ like  $a\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c$ where a, b, c $\in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: An algebraic in $L|\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @FranzS:  Please include complete information in your question.  As it is written, what you have provided is insufficient to answer your query.

Comment: You will need to know a polynomial that $\alpha$ is a root of.

Comment: The answer depends on what cubic $\alpha$ is a root of.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha^2 - \alpha) = \alpha(\alpha - 1)((\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1) = \alpha(\alpha^3 - 1) = \alpha^4 - \alpha$$
$$(1 - \alpha)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\alpha^i} \text{ provided }|\alpha| < 1$$

As you can see, without further information about $\alpha$, there is not much you can do with expressing
$$(\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)(\alpha^2 - \alpha)$$
and
$$(1 - \alpha)^{-1}$$
in the form
$$a\alpha^2 + b\alpha + c$$
where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$.